# Create covariance matrix using ratio and rotation degree

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I am a beginner in Linear Algerbra. I want to create a covariance matrix using given ratio and degree of rotation

For example:
If the ratio is 2 and degree of rotation is 45 the covariance matrix should be:

```
[[2.5, 1.5], [1.5, 2.5]]
```

I tried this:

```
R = np.mat([[np.cos(0.785398), -np.sin(0.785398)], [np.sin(0.785398), np.cos(0.785398)]])
S = np.mat([[2, 0], [0, 2]])
np.cov(S@R.T)
```

I could not get the desired result.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do... where is the data you want to calculate covariance for? Do you want to rotate and scale the result?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate and scale the data as [Burrito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4542084/burrito) said, then this blog will help. It explains everything you want to do along with the code.
[covariance-matrix](https://towardsdatascience.com/interesting-properties-and-use-cases-of-the-covariance-matrix-80d72939c7ab)

Comment: Please avoid posting links without including the relevant code to solve the user's issue.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question when looking for the answer to it myself. Thought I'd come back and post what I found.

It's essentially an eigenvalue problem, so the covariance matrix can be represented by:

[image: Eigen value equation]

Where Q represents the eigenvectors and L is the diagonalised eigenvalues. Because we want to generate the covariance from the rotation and scale, this information must come from there.

To scale a vector/matrix we can use the identity matrix multiplied by a constant, but here we want to use a ratio, so I'm assuming you want the first dimension to be scaled differently to the last one, so we end up with something like:

```
S = np.diag([ratio, 1])
```

One thing to note here is that S is actually the square root of L:

```
L = S**2
```

Coming back to our eigenvectors, we know in linear algebra we use the eigenvectors as a transformation to get the original matrix in a diagonal form, then the inverse of that transformation to return back to the original space. The rotation matrix makes a good eigenvector matrix, with the added benefit that the inverse is just the transpose.

So, putting that all together we end up with:

```
rotation = 45
ratio = 2

theta = np.radians(rotation)
c, s = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)
R = np.array([[c, -s], [s, c]])

S = np.diag([ratio, 1])
L = S**2

R@L@R.T
```

Hope that helps